# Amsmath & Tikz: How to draw horizontal arrow to separate equation steps on same line

Tags: amsmath, tikz-arrows

To save space on my exam solution sheet (format = 2 cols / enumerated), I want to show 2 successive steps on the same line in the solution box (instead of displaying each step on its own line).

This is a rough representation of what I'm seeking:

[image]

I tried using `tikz` package with this command:
`%{\color{blue}\longleftarrow }` Being a `tikz` newbie, the code crashed.

Additionally, adding the **`tikz` package produced an incompatible color warning due to the yellow highlighted box enclosing the final solution.

Your assistance is deeply appreciated! Thank you!

mwe

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[nice]{nicefrac}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{head}
\header{\textbf{ Algebra II: TEST 4 REVIEW (Unit 14: Logarithms)}}
{}
{} 
\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
 }
\newlength{\lwidth}% added <<<<<
\settowidth{\lwidth}{(99)\enspace} % added
\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
    after-skip=2cm,
    label-width=\lwidth, % changed <<<<<<<<<
    item-indent=0pt,   % changed <<<<<<<<<<
    %label-format = \bfseries, 
    %add \bf to make numbers bold <<<<<<<<<<
    label=(\arabic*), % 
    label-offset = -\lwidth,% added <<<<<
    item-format = \hspace{\lwidth},% added <<<<<
    column-sep=2em,    % changed <<<<<<<<<  
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fullwidth}[1]{%
    \vbox{%     
        \leftskip=-\lwidth \rightskip=0pt
        \advance\linewidth\@totalleftmargin%
        \@totalleftmargin=0pt%
        #1}%
    \nobreak
}
\makeatother
\newlength{\SolutionSpace}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}
{\setlength{\SolutionSpace}{5cm}
    \colorsolutionboxes 
\definecolor{SolutionBoxColor}{gray}{0.8}}% solutions are printed
{\setlength{\SolutionSpace}{0cm}
    \colorsolutionboxes 
    \definecolor{SolutionBoxColor}{gray}{1}}% solutions are not being printed
%*********************************************
\begin{document}
%definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}
\begin{tasks}
[style=enumerate](2)
\task![]\fullwidth{\textbf{Solve for $x$. If necessary, round answers to 2 decimal places.}}
%%% Prob #7
\task 
$2 \bm{\cdot}5^{x-3}-7=61$
\begin{solutionorbox}[\SolutionSpace]
$2 \bm{\cdot}5^{x-3}=68$\bigskip
$\dfrac{\cancel{2}\bm{\cdot}5^{x-3}}{\cancel{2}} =\dfrac{68}{2}$\bigskip
$5^{x-3}=35$
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$\log A^7\sqrt{B}$}
\end{solutionorbox}

\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not just `$5^{x-3}=35 {\color{blue}{}\longleftarrow{}}\log5^{x-3}=\log35$` without `tikz`? Do you specifically want that arrow tip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Ti*k*Z:

```
\documentclass[12pt, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{arr/.style = {blue,-{Triangle[angle=60:1pt 3]}, thick,
                       shorten <=2mm, shorten >=2mm}
          } 

\begin{document}
$ 5^{x-3}=35 
    \tikz[baseline=-0.65ex]\draw[arr] (0,0) -- ++ (1,0);
\log 5^{x-3} = \log 35$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
Regarding your comments:

- Term `(0,0) -- ++ (1,0)` define lenght of arrow (actually space for arrow). For it are used relative coordinates, which tell that arrow start at coordinate `(0,0)` and end after 1cm in horizontal direction  (defined by `(1,0)`). For details see Ti*k*Z package documentation, section 13.4 Relative and Incremental Coordinates, pp 146.
- You should be aware that some package load some other package which they need for their works. For example `tikz` among others also load `xcolor` package. If you like to use some options for `xcolor`, you need to load it before `tikz`.
- Below I added your document example, a bit shortened but still contain all package, which you use in in your document.
- In comparison to original answer it contain definition for new command `\arr`, which enable short writing desired arrows between math terms (see comments in MWE code).
- Test of this MWE doesn't gives any warnings or errors.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}
\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[nice]{nicefrac}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\newcommand\arr{\tikz[baseline=-0.65ex]%                                % <--- new
                    \draw[blue,-{Triangle[angle=60:1pt 3]}, very thick, % <--- arrow's style
                          shorten <=2mm, shorten >=2mm                  % shortened visible part of arrow (for gap around it)
                          ] (0,0) -- ++ (1,0);                          % length for arrow space is 1cm
                }
\usepackage{soul}

\newlength{\lwidth}                 % added <<<<<
\settowidth{\lwidth}{(99)\enspace}  % added
\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
    after-skip=2cm,
    label-width=\lwidth, % changed <<<<<<<<<
    item-indent=0pt,   % changed <<<<<<<<<<
    %label-format = \bfseries,
    %add \bf to make numbers bold <<<<<<<<<<
    label=(\arabic*), %
    label-offset = -\lwidth,% added <<<<<
    item-format = \hspace{\lwidth},% added <<<<<
    column-sep=2em,    % changed <<<<<<<<<
}

\begin{document}
\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}

$
5^{x-3}=35
    \arr
\log 5^{x-3} = \log 35
    \arr
x-3 = \log 35
$
\bigskip
$
x=\log 35 + 3 = \colorbox{orange!30}{4.5440680443502756354984773638681}
$
 
\begin{tasks}[style=enumerate](2)
\task![]
\fullwidth{\textbf{Solve for $x$. If necessary, round answers to 2 decimal places.}}
%%% Prob #7
\task
$2 \bm{\cdot}5^{x-3}-7=61$

\begin{solutionorbox}[\SolutionSpace]
$
2\cdot5^{x-3}=68  
    \arr
\dfrac{\cancel{2}\bm{\cdot}5^{x-3}}{\cancel{2}} =\dfrac{68}{2}
    \arr
$
\bigskip
$
5^{x-3}=34
    \arr
x-3 = \log 34
    \arr
$
\bigskip
$
\begin{aligned}
x & = \log 34 + 3 \\
  & = 1.5314789170422551237539087890528 + 3   \\
  & =   \colorbox{yellow}{4.5314789170422551237539087890528}
\end{aligned}
$
\end{solutionorbox}

\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Result of compilation (no warnings, no errors) is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for the fix! What controls the length of the arrow? Also, how does this part of the code work in terms of controlling the arrow? ```(0,0) -- ++ (1,0)```

Comment: The ```tikz``` package causes this warning message in the log: ```Package xcolor Warning: Incompatible color definition```. The error apparently is caused by a conflict with this command which creates a yellow highlight box around the solution: ```\colorbox{yellow}{$2$}```. Is there a way to avoid this conflict? Thank you!

Comment: @SiuslawMath, see addendum to answer.

Comment: ....can't thank you enough for your very detailed and helpful response to my questions! Very generous of you to create the code to short-cut create the arrows!!!

Comment: @SiuslawMath, you are welcome. Happy TeXing!

Comment: ...When I used your revised preamble code, a stray line was produced when I commented out ```%Printanswers``` . Also, these errors: ```Undefined control sequence``` and ```Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).``` and ```Missing number, treated as zero.``` Any idea why? Also, inserting ```usepackage{xcolor}``` immediately before ```\usepackage{tikz}``` did not resolve the incompat color warnings. Thank you!

Comment: @SiuslawMath, my preamble is based on yours, but without definitions for document headers etc. Just used package are the same and in correct order. As far as I see, you not need to load `xcolor` package (this do `tikz` for you). If I correctly understood, you not have problems with my solution but with use of `exam` documentclass. Since I'm not very familiar with it, I suggest you to ask new question where you provide MWE, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: That makes sense. I use the exam doc class because the ```printanswers``` and ```%printanswers``` allows me to re-purpose the doc: (1) create exam without answers (2) then after test is scored, print both the original problem plus the answers to show students the correct step-by-step solutions. However, given the frequent conflicts created by exam class, I'm wondering if I should just create 2 projects: (1) create test in article class. (2) copy the problems into a 2nd exam class doc to show solutions. Thoughts?